# How to move file using File System Task in SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I am very new to SSIS, looking at a package already created by someone else and deployed on SQL server. There is a File System Task that moves files to a network share. I need to change the path of the destination folder. The destination folder requires a domain login.

- I can change the folder path in the
  global variable. Do I have to
  redeploy the package after making
  this change? Can the change be made directly on the SQL server?
- How do I change the user name and password for this network share? Where is this infomation saved? I don't see it in any of the variables.
- There is a SQL Job on the server with the same name, how do I check if this Job is related to the SSIS package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can change the folder path in the variable.  You will need to redeploy after doing this unless the variable is stored in a configuration file.  If that is the case, you can just change the configuration file, and won't need to redeploy.
2. The user name and password will probably be stored in the Flat File connection.  Look at the bottom of the package in the section labelled Connection Manager.
3. If there is a job of the same name, it was most likely created for the SSIS package of the same name.  If you open the job for editing in SSMS, you can look at the job steps and confirm that the dtsrun command references the SSIS package.